# What's the Point of Spam Registrations?

Tags: user-registration

I understand the point of spam messages or posts--to be able to create links for SEO purposes. But since setting up our site, we've been getting dozens of registrations per day. None of these get approved, so they--or the bots--can't post. We even sent a few an e-mail giving the "good news" that they had won a cash prize: but no response. So I'm pretty sure these are bogus registrations.

But still, what's the point?

Comment: Why to ask here? do you think any of us do such things and therefor will have an insight to the why and how? We can guess, but I think no one here can give an authoritative answer.

Comment: Because if you knew why it is being done it might be possible to create better prevention strategies. Not to mention that this is a site for Wordpress developers. You've got a better place to ask?

Comment: why in the name of ... should we know why it is done? and yes the security stack